# Microsoft Word equation navigation reversed

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor

I am using Microsoft Word version 1911 (office 365) with Hebrew (Right to left) documents. When inside an equation in Word with Hebrew text, clicking the right arrow key will move the cursor to the left, and vice-versa with the left key.

For example: "ALT+=", typing "1234" and then pressing "RIGHT" "RIGHT" will position the cursor where the 'x' is: "12X34"

Does anybody know of any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your default text direction is set "Right To Left" as it should be because your document is in Hebrew.

You can change this setting for each paragraph by changing the direction (**not** the alignment) to "Left To Right" every time you use the equation editor.

Comment: And how does the OP change the text direction? Please see [answer] and take our [tour] to learn how to improve your answer.